# Selenium can't open Gitlab login page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing an automated test, using Java (8), Selenium (4) and Chromedriver (98.0).

The test is for a site that requires to login with different third party accounts, one of them being GitLab.

Unfortunately the test always gets stuck while trying to access Gitlab's login page, on the "Checking your browser before accessing gitlab.com" part. If I pause the test on this step and duplicate the tab manually, the newly opened tab will be able to enter and then the first one will be also able to do it (probably because at that point finally has a valid cookie).

I've tried out different solutions but with no luck. Currently this is my code:

```
@Test
public void test() throws MalformedURLException {

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), options);
    driver.navigate().to("https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in");

    new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
            .until(x -> driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-translate='checking_browser']")).size() == 0);
}
```

When trying to use undetected_chromedriver, using Python, it worked, but it's a requirement for me to use Java. Is there something similar for Java or is there an extra ChromeOption that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

need to download chrome driver https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloadshttps://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
and add this code while setting up driver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: I've already tried that, it didn't work.